# PHP read array object from javascript data object

Tags: php, jquery

I create a data object in jquery and I pass this to php with post method

```
var PD = { currentPage : 1, rowCount : 10, search : 5 };

post method --> data = PD
```

In php page if I get the superglobal $_POST I have this

```
var_dump($_POST) --> Array ( [data] => [object Object] )
```

In php how can I do to read $ _POST ['data'] values ?
Thanks

EDIT (full code)

```
var PD = { currentPage : 1, rowCount : 10, search : 5 };    
    PD = JSON.stringify(PD);

redirectPost('index.php', { data : PD });

var redirectPost = function(location, args) {
    var form = '';
    $.each(args, function(key, value) {
        form += '<input type="hidden" name="'+key+'" value="'+value+'">';
    });
    $('<form action="'+location+'" method="POST">'+form+'</form>').appendTo('body').submit();
};
```

PHP

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
var_dump($data); <-- NULL
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['data'])` return?

Comment: You should post your exact javascript code.

Comment: `$_POST['data']['rowCount]` should be what you need

Comment: so, is it 'date' or 'data'?

Comment: @vitr - the name is data

Comment: honestly, this is not a jquery issue, you just stringify the object and send it via html form with a little jquery help, but this is not the jquery ajax call, which we assumed before you posted the full javascript code.

Comment: @vitr - i'm sorry for this, but the problem is that in php returns NULL

Comment: @Gus let's try var_dump($_POST);  
and check your html code, actually, can we see the html source?

Comment: check this http://vitr.biz/1/index.php
this page posts that stuff to index2.php, you may not even notice as it redirects straight after page load

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for the [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)-function. However, this will not create a PHP-object, but it will turn into an array like this: `$data['currentPage']`. See if you get more luck with this:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your JavaScript object has been converted to a string `[object Object]`, you need to `JSON.stringify` your JavaScript object before posting it.

```
var PD = { currentPage : 1, rowCount : 10, search : 5 };
// ensure our data is serialised in a format we can read later with PHP.
PD = JSON.stringify(PD);

post method --> data = PD
```

Once you've received your $_POST data then as Phil points out you should be able to `json_decode` it

Comment: At this point I think you need to post more comprehensive code of the method of posting your data etc. There's clearly something missing.

Answer (score 0):

firs of all, your javascript will never work. There are some javascript issues, like calling a variable before declaration, double quotes in value interfere with json. stringify

```
value="{"currentPage":1,"rowCount":10,"search":5}"
```

doesn't look good at all((
If you fix it like I did here
https://jsfiddle.net/79dLek7p/

```
var PD = { currentPage : 1, rowCount : 10, search : 5 };    
    PD = JSON.stringify(PD);

var redirectPost = function(location, args) {
    var form = '';
    $.each(args, function(key, value) {
        form += '<input type="hidden" name="'+key+'" value=\''+value+'\'>';
    });
    $('<form action="'+location+'"  method="POST">'+form+'</form>').appendTo('body').submit();
};

redirectPost('index.php', { data : PD });
```

you will see the $_POST['data'] as json encoded string, which you can json_decode, as suggested before.